# Screen co-ordinates to Normalised device co-ordinates

Tags: opengl-es

I have screen co-ordinates as x=216,y=726,w=504,h=284 and we need to convert these to normalized device co-ordinates [-1,1] before drawing using glDraw in openglES.
Please any help would be really appreciated. I am relatively new to openglES.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when mapping coordinates from one coordinate system to another, here's the procedure:

```
targetPosition.x = targetLeftMost + (sourcePosition.x / sourceWidth) * targetWidth
targetPosition.y = targetTopMost + (sourcePosition.y / sourceHeight) * targetHeight
```

So for you, it should be:

```
targetPosition.x = -1 + (sourcePosition.x / 504) * targetWidth //(targetWidth = 2?)
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Hi Gil, thank you very much for the quick reply.Similarly is there a way to dynamically calculate texture co-ordinates for the x,y co-ordinates calculated from the above equation.

Comment: you shouldn't need to recalculate the texture coordinates after you do so the 1st time. All you need to do is translate according to your position before calling glDraw.